# converting asciidoc to html - too big result file

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I created huge documentation with Asciidoc. 
It contains about 600 .adoc files. 
When I'm saving this documentation as a html file, I'm getting ~70MB file. It is to big file.

What can I do to create htmls from .adoc files. It's important for me to have table of contents.

I found plugin (https://gist.github.com/mojavelinux/d94372393950ca76d594) to asciidoc, but it doesn't work properly

Greets,
Adam

Answer (score 1):

How does the resulting HTML file look? Doesn’t it contain duplicated stylesheets or similar content?

Part of the problem is that built-in Asciidoctor “HTML5” converter generates really bloated and non-semantic markup (it has nothing in common with HTML5 except the doctype). And the built-in stylesheet is not better. The result is quite hard to process for browser, so large document takes long to render. And the HTML file is also quite big, but I don’t think that this is the only cause of your 70MiB file.

You may try alternative converter [asciidoctor-html5s](https://github.com/jirutka/asciidoctor-html5s/). It generates much cleaner markup, focuses mainly on correct semantics, accessibility and compatibility with common typographic CSS styles. However, I don’t have a complete stylesheet for it yet and it’s not (can’t be) compatible with Asciidoctor built-in styles.

Comment: It doesn't contain duplicated stylesheet and doesn't look bloated.
Html result file created by asciidoctor-html5s is size 60MB and is still to heavy for browser.

Comment: Well, maybe it's just size of the content? You have 600 .adoc files, that's quite a lot. Why do you wanna merge it into a single HTML file?

Comment: When I'm compiling it into one file, I'm getting automatic table of content.